# Skip making Vector-Tiles for higher Zoom (18+)

Tags: vector-tiles, tilestache

I made the switch from raster to [Vector Tiles](https://www.mapbox.com/vector-tiles/) for my maps sometime last year and so far I've been really satisfied with my decision. I have been making tiles from zoom 1 to 21 and it's been a real struggle trying to tile large areas till zoom 21.

I realized that since vector tiles contain just the vector data they are essentially the same for higher zoom levels, just of a smaller extent, so I could skip making the tiles and simply reload the previous zoom level's tiles. I tested it out by limiting my max zoom to 17 and viewing the map at zoom 21 (zoom 17 tiles reloaded at zoom 21) and couldn't find a difference in the rendered map (the missing labels can be handled in my renderer).

This is the original zoom 21( with zoom 21 tiles):
[image]

And this is the zoom 21 with zoom 17 tiles reloaded:
[image]

Can I **skip making tiles for zoom 18+** and use the **zoom 17 tiles till zoom 21** without any problems?

*I am using [TileStache](http://tilestache.org/) to make my vector tiles (for Pakistan only, not globally) and it stops simplifying geometries from zoom 16*

Comment: Are you generating all of your vector tiles up-front? Can you generate them dynamically instead, i.e. only cut a vector tile when it is requested? Something like `node-mapnik` can be used for this. These can still be cached, but you won't need to create them all before you can start rendering them. Globally, zoom 19 has more than **270 billion** tiles.

Comment: generating them dynamically significantly reduces the performance, I do try to generate as much of them up front as I can but I keep the option for generating them dynamically open. I cache the major cities (areas that get viewed often) upfront.

Comment: I am only working on Pakistan for now, not globally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon further testing and research I have found out that I can over-zoom the zoom 17 tiles all the way up to zoom 21 without any problems. Since the VectorTiles contain only the underlying geometry, and I am not simplifying the geometry, I am essentially getting the same information in the tiles just for a smaller extent (when I get zoom 18 onwards tiles).

[This](https://github.com/mapbox/vector-tiles/issues/21) is good explanation of overzooming.